# How to Write Urdu Language in React Native App

Tags: reactjs, react-native, urdu

I am developing a react native app in which I have to use two languages(Urdu & English) at the same time. This means some screens will be in English language and some will be in Urdu.
I have searched about it but found Localization every time which probably not the solution to this problem as I am not translating the whole app.
How I can write both these languages in an app?

Comment: i guess you need this : https://medium.com/@lewie9021/custom-fonts-in-react-native-85d814ca084

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by following steps.

1. Write urdu in inpage.
2. Convert Inpage Urdu to Unicode using any converter online.
3. Paste Converted text in Application inside `<Text> </Text>`.

It will be your urdu text as you want.

You can also use "Jameel Noori Nastaleeq" fonts for better urdu in application.

Comment: Can you please explain more? How did you do this?

Comment: There is a tool called "inpage" which can be used to write urdu. You have to write urdu in that tool or if you have any other tool for writing urdu.
Then you need to convert that inpage urdu to unicode text because mobile apps can't understand inpage format. You can search for inpage to unicode converter online and you will fine many.
Paste the unicode urdu text into your code inside <Text> Component.